# iOS Apple Developer Invitation & Valid Signing Identity

Tags: ios, certificate

I have to publish an iOS App with an Apple Developer Account which is not mine. I got the Developer Invitation to that Account and joined the team. I have to use an existing Distribution Certificate to sign the App but something went wrong because the **valid signing identity for this certificate was not not found**.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is what I did:

1. Joined the new Developer Account
2. Created a new Developer Certificate (created a certificate with the certificate assistant in my keychain and uploaded to the account in order to get my valid development certificate).
3. Certificate got approved from the Admin of the account (downloaded and installed on my mac)
4. Next I downloaded an existing Developer Proivisioning Certificate (downloaded and installed in my mac)
5. XCode says that no valid signing identity for that Development Proivisioning Profile was found. But am I right that this valid signing identity was downloaded in Step 3? Or what do I have to do to get it working? I thought I only need that Development Certificate in order to get all existing Development Provisioning Certificates to work. Or do I need the private key (.p12) exported from the Admin's machine?

If you need some additional information just let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: Have you add the certificate to the provisioning profile you working on? this step should happen after the admin accepts your certificate

Comment: what exactly do you mean? I downloaded both certificates and pulled them over the XCode & Keychain icon the my dock in order to install them.

Comment: After your admin accepts your certificate request ask him to add that certificate to the provisioning profile you working on. And then download the provisioning profile and drag and drop to the xcode

Comment: ah ok in other words - he has to edit the existing development provisioning profile and add my approved developer certificate?

Comment: yep you are correct. In his developer portal, it will show you as a developer. So he needs to add you to the provisioning profile you are using. Then download it and put it to the xcode

Comment: ok thank you very much - so it isnt my fault ;)

Comment: I have added the answer. Please you can mark it as the correct one. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your admin accepts your **certificate request** ask him to add that certificate to the **provisioning profile** you working on. 
Then download the provisioning profile and drag and drop to the xcode